# I have no idea why Eclipse can't recognize the java.io library

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries

I have Java JDK 1.7.0_07 installed and I made sure that the Java build path in Eclipse is pointing to the right directory in my system. How come my machine complains of not having the 'File' object available? I have made sure i imported java.io.*. What could be wrong?

Comment: Does it know what Object or String are? And java.io is a package, not a library.

Comment: would please provide your import code

Comment: Okay, nvm I figured out the problem and it's quite stupid. I'm a newbie to this and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just make sure the *JRE System Library* is part of your build path (see the picture below). Check that the System library is set and if not, click on *Add library* and select *JRE System Library*.

[image]